# Open scanner from web page (JavaEE or asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, jakarta-ee, image-scanner

I know that you cannot access a peripheral (like the scanner) from a web page, but i saw a method for acceding "a TWAIN Scanner" using .net, but it is a paid solution and plus the use has to download and install a file before using the online scanner, and it is only limited to twain scanners (if i got it right?).
Also i saw another method, that consist of downloading a java applet (very old??), but it does not work on google chrome, and need special permission on firefox.

so my question is there any method, using JavaEE or asp.net, to let the user access the scanner from a web page??

Thank you.

Comment: On what operating systems should this solution run? Windows, OS X, any Linux?

Comment: windows, both the client and server

Comment: Would silverlight be an acceptable technology?

Comment: i have no idea how to use it, but if it would fulfill my requirement, im ready to learn it

Comment: Try this [online demo](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Demo/DWT/online_demo_scan.aspx) and see if it meets your needs. It uses a 3rd party scanning SDK though.

Comment: Yes i know that plugin, and it has 2 problems, first in order to use the scanner you to download and install a 3rd party, 2nd its not free...